# Unlock delay for iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, unlock, productivity

So I waste too much time on my phone. Checking Facebook and Twitter, browsing to read unproductive things, etc. I should just stop, but I'm curious if there is a technological deterrent to my habit.

I suspect that an unlock delay would be perfect. If I knew that my phone would take 30 or 60 seconds to unlock, then I would be significantly less likely to pick up my phone at all, when I don't *need* anything. I need to have my phone near me and on for work, but I would like it if the time-wasting aspects of my phone were less convenient.

Is there any sort of setting or app that could help with this?

Answer (score 6):

There's no setting to delay the unlock, but what you could do is go to `Settings` > `Touch ID & Passcode`, switch off `Use Touch ID for iPhone Unlock`, and then switch off `Simple Passcode`.

Switching off `Use Touch ID for iPhone Unlock` will disable your fingerprint's ability to unlock your phone, and switching off `Simple Passcode` will make you write a passcode that can be any length you want, with any characters you want. You can make the only way into your phone long/inconvenient enough to not be worth the hassle of typing on such a regular basis.